# Adding a sorting feature to a navigation bar of a TableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tableview

I am designing a Notes App for an iPad. Right now, I have a UITableView that displays a bunch of notes. When a cell is clicked, another window displays "note title, content, creation time, edit time " .

I would like to add a "Sort By" button in the navigation bar of the Table View to sort by the note's details. I know how to create a plus & info buttons but I am not sure how to create a "Sort By" button. Do I have to create a customized button or is there another way ?

I want to abide by Apple's interface standards, do you have any interface suggestions for the sorting feature, for example should I create 3 buttons, one for each sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a customized button that you add as a right bar button item to the navigation bar. You may even be able to add something in interface builder.

For the sort by, I wouldn't do 3 buttons because that would look a little funky. If I were you I'd take the time and have a sort by button which creates an overlay view and displays it over the table. When you click the sort by button, a dropdown or overlay would appear, then you would have buttons or another tableview in this view that have your 3 options.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used the right bar button and it worked =D My assignment is due along with other assignments and midterms , If I have enough time, I will for sure try the Overlay option.